# SQL IF ELSE followed by INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to do two different INSERT statement depending on a CONSTRAIN exist or not. So far I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu 
ON cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
AND tc.TABLE_NAME = 'table'
AND cu.COLUMN_NAME = 'user'
```

I try to use IF EXIST and ELSE to differentiate two INSERT statement. But apparently I can only use SELECT following an IF ELSE statement

Trying to do something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu 
                ON cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
                WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
                AND tc.TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
                AND cu.COLUMN_NAME = 'user')
    INSERT INTO table1 (username,datainfo) VALUES ('A','test1')
ELSE
    INSERT INTO table1 (username,datainfo) VALUES ('B','test2')
```

Comment: Your best bet with pg is to use the [`ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html) clause of the insert statement.

Comment: Actually I am using this on a nodejs backend to dynamically Insert into two different table. One table has the said constraint and will do an upsert ON CONFLICT, the other doesn't and will do a normal INSERT

Comment: what you are asking for is highly unusual. constraints _should be_ statically defined, except during a database migration, so should be known to your app when it decides which table to insert into. the select query to check that a constraint exists would either always return true or always return false. if you really need to check the existence of the constraint in the database at runtime, you'd have to use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

`IF`s cannot be used in pure SQL. You can either create a function, a procedure or an [`anonymous code block`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-do.html) using `PL/pgSQL` as follows:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu 
                ON cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
                WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
                AND tc.TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
                AND cu.COLUMN_NAME = 'user') THEN
    INSERT INTO table1 (username,datainfo) VALUES ('A','test1');
ELSE
    INSERT INTO table1 (username,datainfo) VALUES ('B','test2');    
 END IF;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```